# SSIS Script Taks: ErrorDescription: The script returned a failure result

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have created one SSIS package and used the script task to assign dynamic Output file name.
This package working on development perfectly. But when I deployed same package on QA Server it getting failed on script Task and getting below error (Version: SSDT 2017):

ErrorDescription: `The script returned a failure result`

Comment: The ScriptTask must be depending on something particular to your development machine such as a file or folder path, assembly or Registry setting. Are you able to edit your question to include the code of the Script Task? (Mask out any confidential information, of course.)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.                                                                                                 Actually Same code used on other package as well and its working fine on QA server.

Comment: If it's the same code used in another package that works fine on QA then there shouldn't be any issue copy-pasting the code from the other package into this one. I doubt it would be so simple, though.